# Changing the format of labels inside the legends in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to customize the `legends` in matplotlib.

I want to order the labels inside the legends horizontally and remove the handle as well. Color of the labels must be same as the line color.

Currently I have set the handle as invisible, but not able to change the ordering of labels.

Looking forward for expert advice.

**Expected output:**

[image]

What I have achieved so far is the following,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
lines=[]
lines.append(plt.plot(x, y1, '-b', label='sine')[0])
lines.append(plt.plot(x, y2, '-r', label='cosine')[0])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
for item_legend,handle,line in zip(plt.legend().get_texts(),plt.gca().get_legend().legendHandles,lines):
    plt.setp(item_legend, color=line.get_color(),size=30)
    handle.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

**output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**
If I set

```
plt.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=2)
```

Labels are aligned in one row but all the previous formatting gets removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it. The key to left alignment here is to use `handletextpad=0` and `handlelength=0`. The `columnspacing` here controls the horizontal space between the two columns of the legend. Putting the handle length to 0 would simply show the legend texts. You can then finally adapt the color of the legend texts according to the respective curves.

```
l = plt.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=2, handlelength=0, handletextpad=0, columnspacing=0.5, fontsize=36)

handles = plt.gca().get_legend().legendHandles

for i, text in enumerate(l.get_texts()):
    text.set_color(lines[i].get_color())
```

**EDIT** (based on the comments)

You can avoid manually specifying the number of columns by using the length of the `lines` as `ncol` while defining the legend as

```
l = plt.legend(loc='upper left',ncol=len(lines), handlelength=-0.2, columnspacing=-0.2, fontsize=36)
```

You can also remove/hide the handle by using the transparency parameter `alpha` by setting it to 0 as

```
handles[i].set_alpha(0)
```

or by hiding it as

```
handles[i].set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa. 1. can we assign n_cols value from some parameter of legends. 2. Is there a better way to remove the handle, instead of making it invisible - guess that's the reason for left alignment problem.

Comment: Really hard for me to tell this. transparency = 0 is also similar to set_visible as false. Can we set it None or something so that left alignment works properly.

Comment: @AI_Learning: I got it. Check my new edit and the corresponding figure

Comment: The key to left alignment here is `handletextpad =0 ` and `handlelength=0`